# How to use geometry reader so that the view does not expand?

Tags: swiftui

I have used geometry reader like this

```swift
GeometryReader { r in
   ScrollView {
      Text("SomeText").frame(width: r.size.width / 2)
   }
}
```

The problem is that the reader expands vertically much like `Spacer()`.
Is there anyway that I can make it *not* do this?

Comment: you want to make the Text view to be half width of ScrollView?

Comment: no, this is just an example.
What I need is what was mentioned in the question. I want to use geometry reader, but I do not want the bad side effect of geometry reader which is --> it expands the entire view both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: If you want the Text view to be half of content size, it cant be done cause the Text is also inside the content itself. :)

Comment: I do not want the text view to be half the content size.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After googling around I found this answer [here](https://www.wooji-juice.com/blog/stupid-swiftui-tricks-single-axis-geometry-reader.html).

Create this new struct

```swift
struct SingleAxisGeometryReader<Content: View>: View {
    private struct SizeKey: PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 10 }
        static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
            value = max(value, nextValue())
        }
    }

    @State private var size: CGFloat = SizeKey.defaultValue
    var axis: Axis = .horizontal
    var alignment: Alignment = .center
    let content: (CGFloat)->Content

    var body: some View {
        content(size)
            .frame(maxWidth:  axis == .horizontal ? .infinity : nil,
                   maxHeight: axis == .vertical   ? .infinity : nil,
                   alignment: alignment)
            .background(GeometryReader {
                proxy in
                Color.clear.preference(key: SizeKey.self, value: axis == .horizontal ? proxy.size.width : proxy.size.height)
            }).onPreferenceChange(SizeKey.self) { size = $0 }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```swift
SingleAxisGeometryReader { width in  // For horizontal
   // stuff here
}
```

or

```swift
SingleAxisGeometryReader(axis: .vertical) { height in  // For vertical
   // stuff here
}
```

With this answer, it’s now generic with no code change.

Comment: This is so useful, can't believe it's not a default setting in geometry reader.

Comment: yea, i think SwiftUI is still a bit rough around the edges

Comment: this view can get messed up in transition animations, beware

Comment: @crow i havent tried animations, maybe someone can improve the response to have a fix

Answer (score 1):

Since background is fit to actual view size always.you can use this trick, adding  GeometryReader in background without changing the size of the view itself.

```
       ScrollView {
        
    }.background(
        GeometryReader { r in
            // stuff
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: This correctly does not let it expand, but i needed the `r` to be available inside ScrollView so that the contents of scroll view can be sized according to `r`

Comment: if you need to take the content size of the scroll view? so then there is a another proper way we can use . so please change the question then i will edit my answer .

Comment: I have edited the question, and have added the `Text()` object inside the scrollView.

Comment: I'm want to use the size in another place as @state, thx for this!

Answer (score -1):

It's somewhat unclear what you're actually trying to do with the views if it's not actually the code you gave at the top. With regards to that, though, you can swap the position of the GeometryReader and the ScrollView. What the GeometryReader does is find the frame of the available space, and it fills it. With a ScrollView the actual height is 0. So, this:

```
ScrollView {
       GeometryReader {r in
          Text("SomeText").frame(width: r.size.width / 2)
       }
    }
```

Comment: put this at the end of the ScrollView.   `.border(Color.black, width: 1)`  You will see that the ScrollView (because of geometry reader) takes up the entire width and height of the screen. I am trying to make this _not_ happen.

Comment: Why? Is there some actual specific problem you're trying to solve? Or are you just hypothetically trying to get a GeometryReader to behave in a way that it doesn't? With regards to my answer above, the ScrollView taking up the full height of the screen actually has nothing to do with the GeometryReader:

Comment: `ScrollView {
            Text("SomeText").frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                
        }.border(Color.black, width: 1)`

Comment: Maybe not the height (in this particular case). But you can see that it does take up the full width right? In other situations, it does takes up the full height.  I guess the point is this. I want to use GeometryReader, but without GeometryReader messing up my views. I currently have a much more complex view, and this sideeffect of GeometryReader is making my Views stretch to maximum capacity. I do not want it to behave this way because it messes up my layout. If i need to be more clear then let me know.

Comment: You DO need to be more clear than that. You need to post actual code. It doesn't have to be exact, but it needs to have some representation of all views involved. Otherwise, the answer to your original question is a definitive 'NO'. There is no way to do this. There is, however, almost certainly a way to get your views to layout properly, and it doesn't necessarily involve using a GeometryReader at all. So, post a more detailed example. Then, someone will likely be able to solve your problem.

Comment: But... the question above is clear right?  If you can find a way to make the code above _NOT_ expand, then this will be a solution to my problem.  I do not understand how my question is NOT clear, when this -> question which asks the exact same thing is very clear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859095/swiftui-using-geometryreader-without-modifying-the-view-size.  For his solution he used a method that I _cannot_ use for my view. Which is why i am asking for a generic solution here. Also, note, I have already posted the generic solution here in my answer on this page.